# Action name/URL name in debuggers using Struts 2

Tags: jsp, configuration, struts2, workflow

This has been bothering me since I started working with this webapp last year (I had no experience with web development) I don't know if this app is structured incorrectly or if this is just *the way it is*.

My `welcome` page is really a login page, and after the user logs in my app goes to a main page, where they have a menu to go to various other functions.

**This is `struts.xml`:**

```xml
<action name="Welcome">
    <interceptor-ref name="newStack" />
    <result name="success">Login.jsp</result>
</action>

<action name="actLogin" class="actionLogin">
    <interceptor-ref name="newStack" />
    <result name="success">HomePage.jsp</result>
    <result name="error">Login.jsp</result>
</action>

<action name="actHomePage" class="actionHomePage">
    <interceptor-ref name="newStack" />
    <result name="viewUsers">  ViewUsers.jsp</result>
    <result name="addUser">    AddUser.jsp</result>
    <result name="viewWidgets">ViewWidgets.jsp</result>
    <result name="addWidget">  AddWidget.jsp</result>
</action>
```

**The JSP files look like this: `Login.jsp`:**

```xml
<s:form action="actLogin" name="formLogin" method="post">
    <s:textfield name="userId" id="txtUserId"/>
    <s:password name="password" id="txtPassword"/>
    .. login submit button ...
</s:form>
```

**`HomePage.jsp`:**

```xml
<s:form action="actHomePage" name="formHomePage" method="post">
. . . menu items that set values for action to pick up to route to the correct page
</s:form>
```

**`ViewUsers.jsp`:**

```xml
<s:form action="actViewUsers" name="formViewUsers" method="post">
    <h2>User List</h2>
    . . .
</s:form>
```

The problem with this is the URL the user sees and the URLs listing the source files in a debugger (Chrome, IE or Firefox) is always wrong. The URL that the user and debugger sees is `Welcome` on the login page (which is OK), but after they log in they see `actLogin.html` on the `HomePage` page, and they see `HomePage.html` on the `ViewUsers` page. The URL is always one behind the page you are actually on because it uses the action name.

Should my login JSP *not* have its form action be named LOGIN because while that is the action being performed, the result of that action goes to `HomePage`?

Is this app structured *weird* and there's a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This happens as a result of the bad workflow design. To correct it you should read about [PRG pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get). You can change

```xml
<action name="actLogin" class="actionLogin">
    <interceptor-ref name="newStack" />
    <result name="success" type="redirectAction">actHomePage</result>
    <result name="error">Login.jsp</result>
</action>

<action name="actHomePage" class="actionHomePage">
    <interceptor-ref name="newStack" />
    <result name="success">HomePage.jsp</result>
</action>
```

other results are not needed, but you can remain them if you need to forward to a different page with the same action in the URL.