# How to redirect request after logoff in Struts 2

Tags: jsp, servlets, struts2, actionresult, valuestack

The project has a servlet which is called when a person logs out.

```
public class LogonServlet extends HttpServlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -4899047924930198118L;

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
    setFirmAndRedirect(request, response);
}

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
    setFirmAndRedirect(request, response);
}

private void setFirmAndRedirect(HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String firm;
    String serverPath = request.getServletPath();

    firm = serverPath.replaceAll("/", "").replaceAll(".logon", "").trim()
                     .toLowerCase();

    request.setAttribute("firm", firm);

    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/logon.do");
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
}
}
```

The servlet tries to forward the request to `logon.do` action of Struts.

Following is my `web.xml` file:

```
<web-app>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.DEFINITIONS_CONFIG</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/tiles-defs.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
    
  <filter>
    <filter-name>HibernateSessionFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.rolfeandnolan.ccp.filters.HibernateSessionFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>

    <!-- Struts 2 -->
  <filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  
  <!-- Should only apply to Alerts Direct requests -->
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>HibernateSessionFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>logon</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.rolfeandnolan.ccp.servlets.LogonServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>logon</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.logon</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

The `LogonServlet` is used to serve the logout requests as per following `struts.xml`:

```
   <action name="logoff"
           class="com.rolfeandnolan.ccp.struts.actions.LogoffAction">
           <param name="allowedRoles">admin,margin,alerts,limitadmin,workfloweditor,eval,theocalc,stress,alertscustomer,useradmin</param>
       <result name="success">/logon.jsp</result>
       <result name="firmlogon" type="dispatcher">
        <param name="location">${firm}.logon</param>
       </result>
    
   </action>
```

On forwarding, it is giving  404 error:

> HTTP Status 404 - /ccpserver/logon.do
> type Status report
> message /ccpserver/logon.do
> description The requested resource (/ccpserver/logon.do) is not available.
> JBoss Web/2.1.3.GA

While hitting the direct URL `http://localhost:8080/ccpserver/logon.do`, it is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `firm` value in the `valueStack` then you don't need a servlet. After log off you should redirect to the login action using a redirect type result.

> ## [Redirect Action Result](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/redirect-action-result)
>
> This result uses the `ActionMapper` provided by the
> `ActionMapperFactory` to redirect the browser to a URL that invokes
> the specified action and (optional) namespace. This is better than the
> `ServletRedirectResult` because it does not require you to encode the
> URL patterns processed by the `ActionMapper` in to your `struts.xml`
> configuration files. This means you can change your URL patterns at
> any point and your application will still work. It is strongly
> recommended that if you are redirecting to another action, you use
> this result rather than the standard redirect result.
>
> See examples below for an example of how request parameters could be
> passed in.
>
> ```xml
> <package name="passingRequestParameters" extends="struts-default" namespace="/passingRequestParameters">
>    <!-- Pass parameters (reportType, width and height) -->
>    <!--
>    The redirectAction url generated will be :
>    /genReport/generateReport.action?reportType=pie&amp;width=100&amp;height=100#summary
>    -->
>    <action name="gatherReportInfo" class="...">
>       <result name="showReportResult" type="redirectAction">
>          <param name="actionName">generateReport</param>
>          <param name="namespace">/genReport</param>
>          <param name="reportType">pie</param>
>          <param name="width">100</param>
>          <param name="height">100</param>
>          <param name="empty"></param>
>          <param name="suppressEmptyParameters">true</param>
>          <param name="anchor">summary</param>
>       </result>
>    </action>
> </package>
> ```
>
> See [ActionMapper](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/mapper/ActionMapper.html) for more details.

---

You can code something

```xml
<result name="firmlogon" type="redirectAction">
    <param name="actionName">logon</param>
    <param name="namespace">/</param>
    <param name="firm">${firm}</param>
</result>
```

---

Comment: The solution worked for me, but still I am not able to get why forward from servlet is not working.

Comment: You shouldn't forward to a servlet, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/31483491/573032

Answer (score 0):

You have `LogonServlet` for log-in for that you are using `/logon.do`. later in same servlet in `setFirmAndRedirect` method why you are forwarding request to same `url`? i.e, `/logon.do`

you need another url like `/logout` which is a servlet that contains your logout code.
and mapping for that logout should be as below:

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("logout");
dispatcher.forward(request, response);

<servlet>
  <servlet-name>logout</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.rolfeandnolan.ccp.servlets.logout</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>logout</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/logout</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: It is not redirecting to the same URL. When we logout, URL is /logoff.do which is served by struts.xml setting and dispatched to ${firmName}.logon  this is a new URL which is served by the LogonServlet which trie to forward it to /logon.do but fails